# VueJS - How to call event on child component from parent v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**PARENT VIEW** I have the following template code:

```
 <template>
     <employee-card
              v-for="employee in employees"
              :key="employee.id"
              :employee="employee"
              >
            </employee-card>
    </template>

<script>
import EmployeeCard from '@/components/employee-card';

export default {
  components: {EmployeeCard},
  computed: mapGetters({
    employees: 'employees'
  }),
  methods: {
    init() {
      this.fetchEmployees();
    },
    fetchEmployees() {
      // here get employees from store
    },
    validateServerEmployeeStatus() {
      // here call ajax to get all employees status
      // loop for each employee card and update the status
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.init();

    // here I guess I should add a setInterval function that runs
    // every 60 seconds and call validateServerEmployeeStatus() function
  }
};
</script>
```

**CHILD COMPONENT** Employee card template is:

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{ employee.name }}
      <br><br>
      Status {{ employee.status }} (updated every 60 seconds)
      </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'EmployeeCard',
  props: {
    employee: {type: Object}
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {}
};
</script>
```

What I need is to call an `API` every 60 seconds, this will return me the `status` of all the employees I have in my child component. So then I have to loop for all the employees and update the status label in each employee card. I think this is the best approach because I save API calls if I do it inside `employeecard`.

> My question is: once the view is rendered in the browser how can I loop through all employee card elements and update a value within a setInterval function thats going to live in the parent template.

Comment: Vue is data driven. The most idiomatic way to do this with Vue would be to set a value on the employee object and the employee cards simply react to changes in their model. There is no need to manually trigger anything. Given you have a `status`, when that value changes, the change should automatically be reflected in the child components.

Comment: Hi Bert, got it, but in my parent view how can I access a specific child component that was rendered with v-for. What I mean is what happen if I just want to change the status of an specific employee.

Comment: Change the *data* of the specific employee. In the parent you have the complete list of employees. If you change that data, changes should be *automatically* reflected in the child that employee was passed to. You don't have to trigger anything.

Comment: Great :), so my setInterval function would just work out of the box this way correct?

Comment: It should, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what I was explaining in comments above.

Vue is data driven. If you change the data, the DOM will automatically be updated.

Below the `status` of each employee is updated every second. Notice that changes are only made in the `EmployeeList` component, not in the `EmployeeCard`, but the DOM is automatically updated to reflect the new status.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("EmployeeCard",{
  props: ["employee"],
  template: `
    <div>
      <strong>{{ employee.name }}</strong>
      <br><br>
      Status {{ employee.status }}
      <hr>
    </div>
  `  
})

Vue.component("EmployeeList",{
  template: `
    <div>
       <employee-card v-for="employee in employees" :employee="employee" :key="employee.id"/>
    </div>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      employees: []
    }
  },
  created(){
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => this.employees = response.data)
    
    // simulated employee validation
    setInterval(() => {
      let status = ["good", "bad", "meh"]
      for (let employee of this.employees){
        // set a random status
        this.$set(employee, "status", status[Math.floor(Math.random()*status.length)])
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.1/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <employee-list></employee-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Just amazing Bert, appreciate it so much. Really